# JLabel not showing up anything

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am learning Java Swing. When I try this, the JLabel is not showing:

```
public class JlabelInJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Creating frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setBounds(420,420,420,520);

        //Setting frame colour
        Color calcColour = new Color(0x696161);
        frame.setBackground(calcColour);

        frame.setTitle("Calculator");

        //Creating Content pane
        Container c = frame.getContentPane();

        //Setting icon for app
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("download.jpg");
        frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());

        //Creating JLabel objects
        JLabel username = new JLabel("username");
        c.add(username);
```

Comment: You made the `JFrame` visible via `frame.setVisible(true)` before adding the components. Setting the `JFrame` visible should be the last thing to do when building your GUI. Please consider the [Java Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for working examples on how to start building swing GUIs.

Comment: `frame.setBounds(420,420,420,520);` 1) That size is a guess. 2) Even if it's a 'correct' guess for your computer, it's wrong on another OS, or with another PLAF. Instead add all the components (with appropriate borders etc. for whitespace) , then `frame.pack()` for the right size. 3) Of course, follow the advice of @maloomeister re setting the frame visible last (right after packing it).

Answer (score 0):

```
//Creating frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setBounds(420,420,420,520);
    //Setting frame colour
    Color calcColour = new Color(0x696161);
    frame.setBackground(calcColour);

    frame.setTitle("Calculator");

    //Creating Content pane
    Container c = frame.getContentPane();

    //Setting icon for app
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("download.jpg");
    frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());

    //Creating JLabel objects
    JLabel username = new JLabel("username");
    c.add(username);
    //Change set-visible after your settings 
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Please add some explanations and point out what was missing in OP's original code

Comment: Can you detect the difference?  Look at the comment of ''//Change set-visible after your settings ''. The means if you set fram.setVisible , the frame will show now. But at the same time,you are not set Jabel username on this frame when it is showing, because of in your case setting jlabel is after fram.setVisible. As a result, you should set fram.setVisible after your  all settings, then show this frame. Do you understand?